# ASA and BVOH adhesion

Tags: filament, adhesion, dual-nozzle, asa

I am printing a mechanical part for my printer.

It's a new mount for my extruders and I have been attempting to use BVOH as a support filament so that when my print is done it will cut down on the need to finish the part and possible mistakes.

My problem is I can get the BVOH to adhere to the bed with no problem and no warping of any kind, but I can't get the ASA to adhere to the BVOH supports. I run the BVOH at 220 °C and the ASA at 250 °C with my fan at 10 % and I am using a Flashforge Creator Pro printer which is mostly enclosed.

Does anyone know of a way to get the ASA to adhere to the BVOH?

Comment: Did you read anywhere that this was possible in the first place?

Comment: Prusa3d recommends BVOH as a water soluable support material.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell by looking at the de-adhesion what isn't sticking?

It may be that printing the ASA at higher temperature is melting the BVOH enough that it doesn't stick, being molten.  If so, then it may be possible to print the first layer of ASA at a cooler temperature, slower if necessary to still succeed at extrusion, with fans blowing.  Then, print the next layer of ASA at a higher temperature, also with fans flowing.

A test might be to print the BVOH, then a layer of ASA, and stop.  Let it cool and test the adhesion.  If it sticks under these conditions, then a better command of the temperature profile may offer a way forward.

Comment: or... just make the interfaces BVOH

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work. I set the heat bed to 110°C and disabled the underlayer of the raft layer. I set the BVOH and the ASA to 235°C after the 4th layer I set the heatbed to 90°C  and after the 6th layer I set the bed down to 60°C so that the BVOH hardened and adhered to the bed making sure that nothing curled or moved. After the print finished it took 24 hours for my BVOH to fully dissolve but thats probably because I set my support to 100% infill. Either way I got a perfect ASA extruder mount